# Multi user login in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a website which have four modules Admin, branch admin, reporter, accountant where each of the respective person can login to their respective page like admin will login to the admin page and reporter will login to it's page, but the code is not working.
When I try login to any module it login only to the admin page and does goes to the branch admin or reporter or accountant.

This is my index.php page

```
<?php
 include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script
 if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
 {
  header("Location: admin.php");
 }
 ?> 

 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>LoginIN</title>
 <link href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="styles/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <header id="top">
 <center><h1>Reporter Management System</h1></center>
 <div class="container">

 <form class="form-signin" role="form"  action ="" method="post">
 <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

 <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
 <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
 <br>
 <div class="checkbox">
 <label>
 <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me
        <br>
 </label>
 </div>
 <input name="submit"button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value=" Sign in">
 <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
 <br>
<a href="">Forgot your password?</a>       
</body>
</html>
```

This is my login.php page

```
    <?php
     error_reporting( E_ALL );
     ini_set('display_errors',1);
      ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
      error_reporting(-1);
       session_start(); // Starting Session
       $error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
      $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    else
    {
    // Define $username and $password
      $usr=$_POST['username'];
      $pwd=$_POST['password'];
     // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id  and password as a parameter
     $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root1", "oec@123") or die('Error Connecting to mysql server');
     // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
     $username = stripslashes($usr);
     $password = stripslashes($pwd);
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($usr);
     $password = mysql_real_escape_string($pwd);
     // Selecting Database
     $db=mysql_select_db('rms',$con);

    // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
    $query = mysql_query("select username, password from login where  password='$pwd' AND username='$usr'", $con) or die('Error querying database');
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $_SESSION['Sl_no']=$rows['Sl_no'];
    if ($rows ==1)
    {

   // Initializing Session
   header("location: admin.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
    }

   elseif ($rows==2)
   {
   header("location: branchadmin.php");
   }
   elseif($rows==3)
  {
  header("location: accountant.php");
  }
  elseif($rows==4)
 {
  header("location: reporter.php");
 }
 else
 {

 $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
 }
 }
 mysql_close($con); // Closing Connection
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: index.php doesn't have a closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: and you're sure you're not seeing any errors/notices/warnings.

Comment: Undefined index: Sl_no in C:\xampp\htdocs\rms\login.php on line 32 but I had already have Sl_no, username and password in login table but showing this error.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you are checking when you do `while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { $_SESSION['Sl_no']=$rows['Sl_no'];if ($rows ==1)` This just fetches a result array as a numerically indexed or associative array. Can you explain to me what these if, if/elses are actually checking?

Comment: I want to fetch the username and password from  the database through the  session variable where I want to pass Sl_no as a session variable. So I stored my session variable in rows. If the row value is 1, it will direct to admin page, if 2 it will direct to branch admin page adn so on

Comment: only first if condition is working and admin page is logging and elseif part is not working

Comment: If can  you suggest me a simpler method, for get logging in to respective module...please do assist

Comment: Please check this video for role based login in php https://youtu.be/SewKh1Uc0CQ

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23726205)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your retrieval and condition statements around this area

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $_SESSION['Sl_no']=$rows['Sl_no'];
    if ($rows ==1)
    {
```

and since the login page is redirecting to the admin.php every time, this could be because you put the number of returned rows in the `$rows` variable like `$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);` and if it is returning one row this would meet the the `if ($rows ==1){header("location: admin.php");}` condition you check later on...

Just an educated (and/or non-educated) guess.

Why don't you put a column in your db that indicates the users level of access. Like `user_level` or something where admin = 1, branchadmin = 2, accountant = 3, etc. and then do a check and re-direct based on that.

So when you check whether the username and password from the form are in the the database and if it is then you could look at their user level to see where to re-direct them.

```
if ($rows === 1){ 
$row_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
if ($row_array['admin_level'] == 1){
   header("location: admin.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}

elseif ($row_array['admin_level']==2){
   header("location: branchadmin.php");
}
elseif($row_array['admin_level']==3){
   header("location: accountant.php");
}
elseif($row_array['admin_level']==4){
  header("location: reporter.php");
}
else{
  $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
}
mysql_close($con); // Closing Connection
```

Does that make sense or am I misunderstanding what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yeah it sounds good but without adding any access level, if I want to achieve with session id or session variable to make it more simpler because reporters are not unique, more number of different reporters may login sometimes. So in that case the access level fails

Comment: I guess I don't really understand. You could have multiple users in your database all with the access level of 4. It does not need to be unique to a single user. Then anytime a user with an access level of 4 logs in it will go to the reporter section.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to use multiple session variables like `$_SESSION['email']` and `$_SESSION['type'].`

Here, $email will be the username of particular user and $type will be the type of user like admin, branch admin, reporter, accountant etc.

These two session variables needs to be set while user is logging in.
For example, consider the following code snippet:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    if($_SESSION['type'] == "admin")
    {
       header('location:admin.php');
    }
    else if($_SESSION['type'] == "reporter")
    {
       header('location:reporter.php');
    }
}
```